# How to remove suggested pages from Facebook feed

Tags: facebook

Good day to you, I use Facebook to contact potential clients and job offerings. However, Facebook keeps suggesting pages and cluttering my feeds with irrelevant content. As a result, I have to scroll far too long to reach important job offering posts. I have searched everywhere in the settings section, nothing is related to the problem. I know that I have to click the hide all option, but this is cumbersome for content from numerous pages keeps showing. Is there anything I can do?